# increment custom primary key without conflict on simultaneous insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which stores citizens information,
the primary key I come up with is a combination of geocode plus the registrant on that location.

the primary key is varchar so I can retain the leading 0 digit.

```
citizen id : 04342601300000001
043426013 is the geocode
00000001 supposedly the increment
```

my procedure is, I will get its integer value and increment it by 1 then I will parse it back to string and add leading 0 if theres any. This is all and good if the system will only be accessible in 1 unit but its not.

How would I assure that the simultaneous inserts gets their proper increments?

This is a PHP Web App

Comment: You would dispense with varchar primary keys and simply use an auto_increment column.  Let the database do the work for you.

Comment: I agree - why are you reinventing the wheel, and creating problems at the same time? Why don't you just use a auto-increment int() column as the primary key?

Comment: You can use zero fill option if you are using mysql database even if it is integer datatype and use an auto_increment for this.

Comment: because there will be a point I need to merge every citizen in different geocode. if different geocode(servers) merge their citizens with both id 1 ,there will be a conflict, so I needed  a custom primary key

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes thanks for the idea Adhan, I figure I can just add a leading 1 so I could avoid using zerofill and proceeded to make it autoincrement, thanks

Comment: :) great job.. welcome